# How to convert Apollo Subscription with Authentication using Apollo Client 2.x from 1.x

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to convert Apollo Client Subscription 1.x to 2.x, but still not working

Existing Code.

subscriptions-transport-ws : 0.8.3
apollo-client : 1.9.3

```
import { ApolloAuthProvider } from '../auth'
import { SubscriptionClient, addGraphQLSubscriptions } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws'
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client'


networkInterface.use([{
  applyMiddleware (req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {}  
    }
    req.options.headers.authorization = 'Basic xxxx'
    next()
  }
}])


const wsClient = new 
SubscriptionClient(ApolloAuthProvider.APISocketEndPoint, {
  reconnect: true,
  connectionParams: {
    'Authorization' : 'Basic xxxx'
  }
})

const networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions = addGraphQLSubscriptions(
  networkInterface,
  wsClient
)

export default (store) => (
  new ApolloClient({
    networkInterface: networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions
  })
)
```

New Code :

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { ApolloAuthProvider } from '../auth'
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link'
import { SubscriptionClient } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws'
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities'
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws'


const getHttpClientConfig = () => {
  let config = {
    uri: ApolloAuthProvider.APIEndPoint
  }

  if (ApolloAuthProvider.isNeedAuthentication()) {
    config.credentials = 'include'
    config.headers = ApolloAuthProvider.getHeader()
  }
  return config
}


const httpLink = new createHttpLink(getHttpClientConfig())

const wsClient = new 
SubscriptionClient(ApolloAuthProvider.APISocketEndPoint, {
  reconnect: true,
  connectionParams: {
    'Authorization' : 'Basic xxxx'
  }
})

const webSocketLink = new WebSocketLink(wsClient)

const requestLink = ({ queryOrMutationLink, subscriptionLink }) =>
  ApolloLink.split(
    ({ query }) => {
      const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query)
      return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription'
    },
    subscriptionLink,
    queryOrMutationLink,
  )

const router = ApolloLink.from([
  requestLink({
    queryOrMutationLink: httpLink,
    subscriptionLink: webSocketLink,
  }),
])



export default (store) => (
  new ApolloClient({
    link: router,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  })
)
```

expected : working normally
actual result :
client.js:426 WebSocket connection to 'wss://' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue might be with the Config object that you pass to the SubscriptionClient

Below is some code that works for me. It's not exactly the same setup that you have (it fetches a bearer token from localstorage instead of basic auth) but I think it should point you in the right direction.

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws';
import { GRAPHCOOL_HTTP_ENDPOINT, GRAPHCOOL_WS_ENDPOINT, JWT_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY } from './constants';
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities';
import { split } from 'apollo-link';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: GRAPHCOOL_HTTP_ENDPOINT
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // Get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem(JWT_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ""
    }
  };
});

const wsLink = () => {
  // Get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem(JWT_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
  return new WebSocketLink({
    uri: GRAPHCOOL_WS_ENDPOINT,
    options: {
      reconnect: true,
      timeout: 30000,
      connectionParams: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        authToken: token
      }
    }
  });
};

// using the ability to split links, you can send data to each link
// depending on what kind of operation is being sent
const link = split(
  // split based on operation type
  ({ query }) => {
    const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
    return kind === "OperationDefinition" && operation === "subscription";
  },
  wsLink(),
  authLink.concat(httpLink)
);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Comment: This just returns data in the form of `"payload":{"Authorization":"Bearer [object Object]","authToken":{"_40":0,"_65":1,"_55":"sessionid=zgcelooi0tbq5kijz4w2qnrhjeehunf2","_72":null}}}`

Comment: @yokhen your bearer token should be a string not an object. I think this likely happened when you saved it to local storage - you saved an object and it got stringified

Comment: It's a promise result, but yeah, not sure how to make it into a string.

Comment: Async await or .then

Comment: `AsyncStorage` (react native) is already async. `await` gives error `TypeError: bundle.added is undefined` and `.then()` will not return the result in time and never initialize `connectionParams`. But thanks for the suggestion.